# Hosting website on AWS but bought domain from google?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-domain-api

I bought a domain (let's say example.com) from google domains a couple of days back, but found out their web hosting is terrible. They only allow me use one of their partner hosting services. I want a simple ssh/ftp based web hosting service, where I can simply dump the html files.

So, I turned to AWS webservices to host my website. Everything works well, until I want to assign it a domain name. AWS assigned me a domain like "mytest-bucket.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/", but I want to use my bought domain.

AWS allows me to buy a new domain from it, but I already have one (example.com), and want to make AWS host my website under that domain name.

Apologies if this is a newbie mistake/question but I am new to commercial web-hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a option in AWS Route53 where you can transfer domain to AWS. Check this guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html

Another way is you can change the DNS servers to Route53. Check this guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html

Another option is you can add `"mytest-bucket.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"` as a C-name to your domain in Google and your domain "example.com" will start showing the website.